# Gson Generics attribute

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I have a question about GSON library

Here is my source code of a class

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public int count;
    public ArrayList<T> items;


    public Response()
    {

    }
}


public class AudioDto
{
    public long id;

    public long owner_id;

    public String artist;

    public String title;

    public long duration;

    public String url;

    public long lyrics_id;

    public long album_id;

    public long genre_id;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "AudioDto [id=" + id + ", owner_id=" + owner_id + ", artist=" + artist + ", title=" + title + ", duration=" + duration + ", url=" + url + ", lyrics_id=" + lyrics_id + ", album_id=" + album_id + ", genre_id=" + genre_id + "]";
    }



}
```

And here

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Response<AudioDto> response = new Response<AudioDto>();
        response = gson.fromJson(responseElement, response.getClass());
```

**The question is:**

How to make GSON deserialize JSON string into `Response` object and all items to `AudioDto` object. If I manually specify `ArrayList<AudioDto>` it takes into account that items in "items" field are objects of type AudioType but with parameterized type it seem like it is casting it to Object class.

Here is JSON String

```
{"count":166,"items":[{"id":231270625,"owner_id":205245503,"artist":"John Newman","title":"Love Me Again","duration":235,"url":"http://cs9-2v4.vk.me/p20/1ee1a056da24cb.mp3","lyrics_id":111547947,"genre_id":17},{"id":230612631,"owner_id":205245503,"artist":"Florence and The Machine","title":"No Light, No Light","duration":274,"url":"http://cs9-5v4.vk.me/p19/51a5b460796306.mp3","lyrics_id":20459437,"genre_id":18},{"id":230612324,"owner_id":205245503,"artist":"Backstreet Boys","title":"Incomplete","duration":239,"url":"http://cs9-4v4.vk.me/p13/b8dcc4cee8bf03.mp3","lyrics_id":268139,"genre_id":1}]}
```

Comment: please post Json String (responseElement) that you want to deserialize

Comment: Also please provide your class `AudioDto`

Comment: Provided as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't use `ArrayList<T> items;` because Gson tries to converts it to `LinkedList`.

So use  `List<T>` instead.

After, you can try:

```
GsonBuilder gsonB = new GsonBuilder();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Response<AudioDto>>() {}.getType();
//Response<AudioDto> response = new Response<AudioDto>();  // you don't need this row

Response<AudioDto> response = gsonB.create().fromJson(responseElement, collectionType);

//assert(response != null);
```

BTW, use `Gson gson = new Gson();` instead `GsonBuilder gsonB = new GsonBuilder();`.

Nothing to configure there.

**About  type**

As I know you can't create `Type` of `<T>`. But you can use `Type` of `<AudioDto>` instead:

*Launcher class*

```
....
LoadJson<AudioDto> lj = new LoadJson<AudioDto>();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Response<AudioDto>>() {}.getType();        
Response<AudioDto> response  = lj.load(responseElement, collectionType);
```

*LoadJson class*

```
 public class LoadJson<T> {

 Response<T> load(String responseElement, Type classType){

  Gson gson = new Gson();

    Response<T> response = gson.fromJson(responseElement, classType);

  return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: That' what I need ! I have been trying something like that, although, I was using ArrayList instead of List. Thank You !!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do something like that:

`public class Response<T>
{
 public int count;
 public List<T> items;
 public Type classType = new TypeToken<Response<T>>() {}.getType(); 
}`